# Enumerate all function descriptors from within an Azure function invocation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a precompiled function C#/.NET and I would like to list all the `FunctionDescriptor` instances. Something similar to how the `ApiExplorer` works in WebApi 2.

Is there such an API? I've only been able to get at the metadata for the currently running function, not all the other functions contained in a function project.

I guess I can read the `function.json` file and go from there but I was hoping that there actually was a simple public API to actually enumerate all the functions that can be invoked, this to not have to implement HTTP binding work that has already been implemented.

...or even if there's a way to simply read the `function.host` file. (and of course, I know that I can simply read the file but you have to map the types and figure out the bindings, this is what I was hoping there would be a somewhat straightforward API for)

I've checked around the source but I'm getting turned around and a lot of the APIs appear to be `internal`

Comment: Are you looking for the OpenAPI definition of the functions ? If so, it can be generated from the portal

Comment: @Thomas No, I need the actual function `FunctionDescriptor`. You can get the function descriptor for the current executing property from `request.Properties` but I need it for all functions in the current `context`.

Comment: This would be very useful for extracting a swagger-like view on the functions. Currently the only way to do it is to extract the types from the assembly and filter on custom attribute FunctionNameAttribute

Comment: @HoriaToma say that here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1602

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListFunctions API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Functions-API#listing-functions) from Azure REST API

```
GET /subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{functionapp}/functions?api-version=2015-08-01
```

I don't think you can get info about other Functions from the execution context

Comment: This is like reading the `functions.json`, it will give me something other than a useful `FunctionDescriptor`. Not only that, I have to manage additional credentials and incur the cost of a service request to the resource manager.

Comment: The `ExecutionContext` only contains information about the currently running function. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function

Comment: As @Mikhail mentioned, there is no way to get that sort of information from within your function now. You can open an issue on the `azure-functions-host` repo you linked to if you want to discuss adding that. The closest thing to this is this static api https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs#L1051 but it's not exactly what you're asking for

Comment: @ahmelsayed I have already done that, and it's actually the wrong repo, the functionality is stored in the `azure-webjobs-sdk` you can follow my progress here, so far ZZzz... https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1602